# What database management system uses "-- -" for comments?

Tags: sql, database

In SQL, the cmd for comments is "--" or /* */. But at the college, we are studying a system that uses `"-- -"` for setting comments. Can anyone tell me what kind of database management system it is ?

Comment: I think none of the ones in the tags, or all of them, if you remove the double quotes (the - at the end is superfluous)..

Comment: Never seen that one before. What's stopping you asking your college?

Comment: @MattGibson, it is a challenge and I have to discover the DMS behind the scene

Comment: Are you sure the `-- -` is the comment syntax?  ie. try removing the last hyphen and see if it still acts as a comment - it could just be someone formatting their comments' text to start with a hyphen, with the first 2 saying "this line's a comment".

Comment: @maraca of course not

Comment: @JohnLBevan it does not work with "--" only

Comment: @WildThing Does it work with "-- "? (Note the space. MySQL, unlike other systems, requires the space after the "--".)

Comment: Perhaps there are other ways to determine which database system is in use. For instance, if `SELECT * FROM DUAL` works there's a fair chance you're looking at an Oracle database. Other DBMS's may have their own quirks. Best of luck.

Comment: The space may be required by other systems.  After all "1--1" is a valid expression (it could evaluate to "2"), although "1 -- 1" is more obviously a comment.